# Magento Different Store Views Different Messages

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view

I am currently running on two store views: "ENGLISH" and "BAHASA INDONESIA".

I've configure a header message(Free Shipping for all SG Orders S$20) on top of the site for ENGLISH store view. 
How do I configure a separate header message for BAHASA INDONESIA store view.

Here my code for ENGLISH store.

```
 <div class="divGlobalHeader">
<div class="divGlobalHeaderNews">FREE SHIPPING FOR ALL SG ORDERS S$20</div>
<div class="divGlobalHeaderUtility">
  <div class='divGlobalHeadercurrency'>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="store-language-container">    
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divGlobalPersonal">
  <div class="divGlobalLogin">
  <ul>
        <!--<li><a href="<?php echo $baseurl ?>customercare"><?php echo $this->__('CUSTOMER CARE'); ?></a></li>-->
    <!--li><a href="<?php echo $baseurl ?>ordertracking"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER TRACKING'); ?></a></li-->
    <?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $baseurl ?>customer/account/login"><?php echo $this->__('Sign In / Register'); ?></a></li>
    <?php }else{ ?>
            <li><a href=" https://www.fat.asia/customer/account/login/">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $baseurl ?>customer/account/logout"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Out'); ?></a></li>

            <?php }?>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have done the same thing very easy way if the text is static not coming from db then you can do following

1) create 2 `cms-static` block with same name and `identifier` forexmple `myidentifier`

2) one would be for `ENGLISH` store view another for `BAHASA INDONESIA`.

3) call your cmsblock in phtml via this code `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('myidentifier')->toHtml() ?>`

And it will check for current store static block and call right cms-static block

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the translate string in Language specific CSV file.

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('FREE SHIPPING FOR ALL SG ORDERS S$20');?>
```

Map the text :

```
app/locale/{lang_ISO}/Mage_Catalog.csv
```

Add your text.

```
"FREE SHIPPING FOR ALL SG ORDERS S$20","My other language"
```

**As language translate fall back, one more option**

```
<?php echo $this->__('Text here'); ?>
```

Add like:

```
app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/locale/{lang_ISO}/translate.csv

"FREE SHIPPING FOR ALL SG ORDERS S$20","Translation here"
```

E.g.: In your theme folder:

```
/locale/fr_FR/translate.csv

"FREE SHIPPING FOR ALL SG ORDERS S$20","My other language"
```